# AngularJS catch ideling promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´m currently trying to write some kind of configuration service. The service delivers a path to another server. This path will be tested for validity with a ping function using the received path. In case the path points to a non existing server there will be no promise and the whole app gets stuck due to actions which should normally take place after the promise is delivered using a `.then(function (data){ });` in the code.
So is there a way how to catch such a missing/pending promise to prevent freezing my app?

Here is the code in the AngularController (gets triggered by button)

```
applicationPingService.ping(path)
.then(function(successStatus){
    if(successStatus == true){

        //Some code here

    }
    else{
        //Some other code here
    }
});
```

This is the called Service.
It takes a path like `http://localhost:8080` and tries to reach a `blank.html` page to check the status code if the server is up or not.

```
app.service('applicationPingService', ['$http', '$q', 'globalValue', function($http, $q, globalValue) {

    this.ping = function(path)
    {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: path + "/blank.html" 
        }).then(function(response)
        {
            if(response.status == 200)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }

        });
    };
}]);
```

**This is just an example, but I also want to know an universal way how to catch idling and missing promises**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this example at a very good [tutorial page for promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/):

```
var jqDeferred = jQuery.ajax('http://localhost/blank.html');

jqDeferred.then(function(response, statusText, xhrObj) {
  alert('success');
}, function(xhrObj, textStatus, err) {
  alert('error');
});
```

Sometimes a servers response takes way too long. Then you could work with your own timeout and use this:

> Promise.race(array); Make a Promise that fulfills as soon as any item
>   fulfills, or rejects as soon as any item rejects, whichever happens
>   first.

Answer (score 0):

There is [`$q.race`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#race) method in Angular 1.5 that does that:

```
var timeoutPromise = $timeout(() => $q.reject('timeout'), 5000);

$q.race([pingPromise, timeoutPromise]]).then(...);
```